# How can I access global variable in vue 3 outside vue component?

Tags: vue.js, global-variables, vuejs3

I defined my global variable in main.js file like this

---

```html
const app = Vue.createApp({})
   app.config.globalProperties.$myGlobalVariable = globalVariable***
```

and then when I tried to access this variable $myGlobalVariable in other js file it is undefined, but I can access in vue components.

In the vue 2 it is possible to access both in js file and vue components. I hope you gonna help me :)

Comment: "when I tried to access this variable $myGlobalVariable" - how?

Answer (score 1):

In order to access a global Vue variable outside of a Vue component you have to:

**1. Export the app instance**

```js
/* main.js */

export const app = Vue.createApp({})
app.config.globalProperties.$myGlobalVariable = globalVariable
```

**2. Import the app instance in the other JS file**

```js
/* other.js */

import { app } from '@/main.js'
console.log(app.config.globalProperties.$myGlobalVariable)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for trying to help me. Unfortunatelly  it is not working. I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'app' before initialization" when I try to access in other.js file.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

**1. Export the global properties**

```js
/* main.js */
const app = createApp(App)

const { globalProperties } = app.config
globalProperties.foo = 'FOO'
globalProperties.bar = () => console.log('BAR')

app.mount('#app')
export default globalProperties
```

**2. Import the global properties in another JS file**

```js
/* other.js */
import globalProperties from '@/main'

console.log('foo', globalProperties.foo)
globalProperties.bar()
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'App' before initialization